# How to give a JList an ID and name?

Tags: java

I have a simple database with 2 columns (ID, Firstname). Now I display each Firstname from my table as an List Item. That works so far. What I want to do is connect my ID from my db table with the firstname cause if i click on a list item the data will be shown in a textfield.

I've created a helper class that has the Name and ID as fields.

```
public class ListDataHelper {
    private int id;
    private String name;

    public ListDataHelper(int id, String description) {
      this.id = id;
      this.name = description;
    }

    public int getId() {
      return id;
    }

    public String getName() {
      return name;
    }

    public String toString() {
      return name;
    }
}
```

My main class looks like this and it works so far.

```
private void getAllAccounts(){
        listAccounts.removeAll();
        try{
            String sql="select * from accounts";
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            DefaultListModel DLM = new DefaultListModel();
            while(rs.next()){
                DLM.addElement(new ListDataHelper(rs.getInt("ID"), rs.getString("FirstName")));
            }
            listAccounts.setModel(DLM);
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        finally {
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

But I'm stuck at the point when I want to retrieve data. I don't know how to use my created helper class or how to get the ID from the selectedValue.

```
private void getAllData() {
        String data =listAccounts.getSelectedValue();
        String sql="select * from accounts where ID=?";
        try{
            pst=conn.prepareStatement(sql);
            pst.setString(1, data);
            rs=pst.executeQuery();
            while(rs.next()){
                String add1 =rs.getString("ID");
                txtID.setText(add1);
                String add2 =rs.getString("FirstName");
                txtFirstName.setText(add2);
                String add3 =rs.getString("LastName");
                txtLastName.setText(add3);
                String add4 =rs.getString("Cheque");
                txtCheque.setText(add4);
                String add5 =rs.getString("Savings");
                txtSavings.setText(add5);
            }
        }
        catch(Exception e){
            JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, e);
        }
        finally {
            try{
                rs.close();
                pst.close();
            }
            catch(Exception e) {
            }
        }
    }
```

When I compile the code I get the following error:

> Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException:
>   ccibank.ListDataHelper cannot be cast to java.lang.String

Thanks already in advance! :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As always, everything would be simpler by reading [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/DefaultListModel.html).

As you can see immediately if you click the link (or if you just read the warnings emitted by the compiler), `DefaultListModel` is a generic class, just like a Collection. So you're supposed to specify the type of objects that you put in such a model. You're not putting Strings inside. You're putting instances of `ListDataHelper`. So it should be declared as

```
DefaultListModel<ListDataHelper>
```

If you browse to the [JList documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html), you'll see that it's also a generic type: it contains the elements of the same type as its list model. So it should be declared as

```
JList<ListDataHelper>
```

Now, what do you get when you call `getSelectedValue()` on a JList? Again, read [the documentation](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/javax/swing/JList.html#getSelectedValue--): You get an object of the generic type E. In this case, the generic tpe E is `ListDataHelper`. This makes perfect sense, doesn't it? If you store objects of type `ListDataHelper`in the list, the selected value is not a String. It's a `ListDataHelper`.

So the code should be:

```
ListDataHelper selectedAccount = listAccounts.getSelectedValue();
```

Another thing that strikes me is that, even though your code doesn't compile, you haven't posted the compilation error(s) in your question. Why is that? The compilation errors indicate what is wrong, and where. Reading the error is the first thing you should do when you have an error. Don't ignore errors. Reading (the errors, the documentation), is extremely important whe programming.

Comment: Thanks for your anwser. Yes I should read the documentation you are right. 

When I compile my code it runs at that point into an error when I select a value from my Jlist.

Exception in thread "AWT-EventQueue-0" java.lang.ClassCastException: ccibank.ListDataHelper cannot be cast to java.lang.String

And If I add the code you mentioned above: ListDataHelper selectedAccount = listAccounts.getSelectedValue(); my IDE says: string cannot be converted to ListDataHelper

I will try to read the docs to get a better understanding what I'm doing

Comment: I know that. But why don't you read the error. Again, you posted that you had an error without saying **what** the error is. **I** know what the error is just by reading the code, but you don't. So why not read the error?

Comment: Sorry I was editing the text .. Im quiet new to Java and stackoverflow ...

Comment: How have you declared your `listAccounts` variable?

Comment: 'listAccounts' is my variable name for my Jlist

Comment: That's not what I asked. I asked how you declared it. You declared it as `JList<String> listAccounts`, right? But what does my anser say about how it must be declared? Does the list contain Strings? What does it contain? Read my comments and my answer, carefully.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/183069/discussion-between-florian-and-jb-nizet).